# Missing Permutations during Recursion

Tags: go, recursion

I have go a sample recursive code in go playground, there are 2 "?", the target is to generate all binary strings replacing ? with 0 or 1 ,  it supposes to display 4 results, but only display 3. ie missing 1100101

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"strings"
    //"strconv"
)

func main() {
    str := "1?0?101"
    mstr := []byte(str)
    q := []byte("?")[0]
    a := []byte("0")[0]
    b := []byte("1")[0]
    fmt.Println(mstr)
    allstr(mstr, 0, len(mstr), q, a, b)

}

func allstr(mstr []byte, index int, size int, q, a, b byte) {

    if index >= size {
        fmt.Println(string(mstr))
        return
    }
    if mstr[index] == q {
        mstr[index] = a
        allstr(mstr, index+1, size, q, a, b)

        mstr[index] = b
        allstr(mstr, index+1, size, q, a, b)

    } else {

        allstr(mstr, index+1, size, q, a, b)
    }

}
```

Go playground:  https://play.golang.org/p/4e5NIOS9fG4

Output:

```
[49 63 48 63 49 48 49]
1000101
1001101
1101101
```

Comment: Why do you think this is supposed to display 8 results? What is the code supposed to accomplish?

Comment: I updated the code a bit, to suppose to display 4, but only display 3. add  the missing one in the question . thanks Jim

Answer (score 2):

You need to undo the writes to the master byte-slice during recursive-backtracking:

```
if mstr[index] == q {
        mstr[index] = a
        allstr(mstr, index+1, size, q, a, b)

        mstr[index] = b
        allstr(mstr, index+1, size, q, a, b)

        mstr[index] = q         // <--- add this
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-JEsVGFcsQo